# Parametrize URL variable WebSocket

Tags: jmeter

I testing backend application, which is in NodeJS and Java technology. communication: WebSocket in NodeJs part and HTTP in Java part) in JMeter I must parametrize URL, to switch between development URL, production and prepod

I did it by CSV file. I created folder CSV, in the folder where I have Jmeter 5.0. I prepare 3 CSV file

still, don't run this test. When I wanted start test, in View Result Three don't have any test run.
I set this:
CSV Data Set Config –

```
${__P(environment,development)}.csv

WebSocket Open Connection
Serwer URL – ws
Server name or IP - ${host}
User Defined Variables 
Name:           Value
Protocol.     ${__P(protocol,)}
Host             ${__P(host,}
In CSV file I set this:

protocol,   host
http,   10.219.227.66
ws, 10.219.227.66

protocol,   host        
https,  prepod.myprepod.io
ws, prepod.myprepod.io

protocol,   host        
https,  production.myproduction.io
ws, production.myproduction.io
```

please help me and show what is wrong, and what exactly I must improve this, because I very tired this topic yet

Yes in logs I have this wrong

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File development.csv must exist and be readable
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:424) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:340) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:324) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:272) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    ... 8 more
2018-10-19 14:29:30,727 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Authorize success 1-1
2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2018-10-19 14:29:30,728 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, just

1. Make sure you have `development.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Remove [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) as it is not required and may cause problems

If you won't see your test producing any results make sure to check out *jmeter.log* file - it's being generated in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation each time you launch JMeter.

JMeter log file can also be accessed using [Log Viewer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) - click yellow triangle with exclamation mark at upper right corner of JMeter GUI and jmeter log will be shown at the bottom.

Ideally there should be no red number right hand of the triangle, if you see them - this is the number of issues in your test plan.

In the below image JMeter cannot start the test as it is not able to find `development.csv` file:

[image: JMeter log file]

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more hints on getting the bottom of your test problem.